# Lists and arrays, part by part

Tags: code-golf, number, matrix, multiple-holes

In this challenge, you'll get four different but somewhat related tasks that must be solved in a specific manner. First, I'll explain the tasks, then follows an explanation of how you must solve it.

Your code should for all four tasks take two positive integers as input: `n,m`, where `n<m`. All tasks must be solved in the same language. The orientation of matrices are optional (n-by-m may be interpreted as "n rows, m columns", or "n columns, m rows").

#### Task 1:

Create (and output/print) a vector / list consisting of the elements: `n, n+1 ... m-1, m`. So, for `n=4, m=9`, you should output: `4,5,6,7,8,9`.

#### Task 2:

Create (and output/print) a matrix / array / list of lists (or equivalent) looking like this:

```
n,   n+1, ... m-1, m
n+1, n+2, ... m-1, m+1
...
n+m, n+m+1, ... 2*m-1, 2*m
```

For `n=4, m=9` you should output:

```
4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9
5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10
...
13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18
```

#### Task 3:

Create (and output/print) an n-by-m multiplication table (on any suitable format). Example for `n=4, m=9`:

```
1   2   3  4
2   4   6  8
3   6   9  12
4   8  12  16
5  10  15  20
6  12  18  24
7  14  21  28
8  16  24  32
9  18  27  36
```

#### Task 4:

Output / print a vector / list consisting of the elements in the multiplication table from task 3, sorted in ascending order, keeping duplicate values. For `n=4, m=9`, you should output: `1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 6, 6, 6, 7, 8, 8, 8, 9, 9, 10, 12, 12, 12, 14, 15, 16, 16, 18, 18, 20, 21, 24, 24, 27, 28, 32, 36`.

## The challenge:

Now, all the tasks above are quite trivial. The real challenge here is that the code for task 2 must start with the code for task 1, the code for task 3 must start with the code for task 2 and the code for task 4 must start with the code for task 3.

**To make it more clear:**

Suppose the [code for **Task 1**](https://tio.run/nexus/octave#@@@gkaeTq6mRZ5Wraf0/Ma9Yw0THUvM/AA) is (works in Octave):

```
@(n,m)(n:m)
```

Then your [code for **Task 2**](https://tio.run/nexus/octave#@@@gkaeTq6mRZ5Wrqa1hACTVrf8n5hVrmOhYav4HAA) could be (works in Octave):

```
@(n,m)(n:m)+(0:m)'
```

The code for task **Task 3** must be (doesn't work in Octave):

```
@(n,m)(n:m)+(0:m)'"Code_for_task_3"
```

And finally, the code for **Task 4** must be (doesn't work in Octave):

```
@(n,m)(n:m)+(0:m)'"Code_for_task_3""Code_for_task_4"
```

---

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the submission with the shortest code for task 4 in each language wins. As always: Explanations are highly encouraged.

Comment: Just to be clear, I'm going to guess that this is against the spirit of the challenge, but is it permissible to start the next task's code with a redirect to STDERR `>2;` so that the previous task's code is essentially rendered a no-op?

Comment: @AdmBorkBork, there's no such thing as "the spirit of the challenge" on PPCG :P [Yes, that's OK](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4781/31516).

Comment: Does the multiplication table need to be padded nicely?

Comment: @HyperNeutrino, no.

Comment: When you say "positive integer", do you mean `0<n<m` or `0<=n<m`?

Comment: `0<n<m` @valueink

Answer (score 6):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 12 bytes

#### Task 1

```
r
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/jelly#@1@kfXifQZFK7f/Dy90VHu7Y/qhhjoJzYk6OQmJeikJBUWpJSSWQyswr0fv/3@S/JQA)

#### Task 2

```
r+þ0r$}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/jelly#@1@kfXifQZFK7f/Dy90VHu7Y/qhhjoJzYk6OQmJeikJBUWpJSSWQyswr0fv/3@S/JQA)

#### Task 3

```
r+þ0r$}
×þ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/jelly#@1@kfXifQZFKLdfh6Yf3/T@83F3h4Y7tjxrmKDgn5uQoJOalKBQUpZaUVAKpzLwSvf//Tf5bAgA)

#### Task 4

```
r+þ0r$}
×þFṢ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/jelly#@1@kfXifQZFKLdfh6Yf3uT3cuej/4eXuCg93bH/UMEfBOTEnRyExL0WhoCi1pKQSSGXmlej9/2/y3xIA)

### How it works

#### Task 1

`r` is the *dyadic range* atom and does exactly what the task asks for.

#### Task 2

A dyadic chain that begins with three dyadic links is a *fork*; the outmost links get evaluated first, then the middle link is called with the results to both sides as arguments.

- `r` behaves as before, yielding **[n, …, m]**.
- `0r$}` is a quicklink (or quickquicklink, if you will).

  The quick `$` (monadich chain) consumes the links `0` (yield **0**) and `r` (dyadic range) and turns them into a monadic chain. When called with argument **k**, this will yield **[0, …, k]**.

  The quick `}` (right argument) takes the quicklink created by `$` and turns it into a *dyadic* link that calls `0r$` with `0r$}`'s right argument.

  `0r$}` will be called with left argument **n** and right argument **m**, so `0r$` is alled with argument **m** and yields **[0, …, m]**.
- `+þ` is another quicklink. `þ` (table) will call `+` (addition) for every element in its left argument and any element in its right argument, grouping the results for each right argument into a single row.

  `+þ` will be called with left argument **[n, …, m]** and right argument **[0, …, m]**, yielding the desired table.

#### Task 3

Every line in a Jelly program defines a different link. The last one is the *main link* and, like C's `main` function, is the only link that is executed by default. The remaining links can be called from the main link, but we won't do this here.

As before, `þ` (table) will call `×` (addition) for every element in its left argument and any element in its right argument, grouping the results for each right argument into a single row.

Since both arguments to `×þ` are integers, `þ` casts them to ranges, transforming the arguments **n** and **m** into **[1, …, n]** and **[1, …, m]**.

#### Task 4

`×þ` works as before. The following links are monadic, making them *atops*, i.e., they are applied on top of the previous ones.

After executing `×þ`, `F` flattens the resulting 2D array, and `Ṣ` sorts the resulting 1D array.

Answer (score 5):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <s>18</s> 17 bytes

**Task 1**

```
Ÿ
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/nexus/05ab1e#@390x///JlyWAA)

**Task 2**

```
Ÿ²FD>})
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/nexus/05ab1e#@390x6FNbi52tZr//5twWQIA)

**Task 3**

```
Ÿ²FD>})v¹LN*})¦
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/nexus/05ab1e#@390x6FNbi52tZplh3b6@GnVah5a9v@/CZclAA)

**Task 4**

```
Ÿ²FD>})v¹LN*})¦˜{
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/nexus/05ab1e#@390x6FNbi52tZplh3b6@GnVah5adnpO9f//JlyWAA)

### Explanations

**Task 1**

```
Ÿ     # range[n ... m]
```

**Task 2**

```
Ÿ        # range[n ... m]
 ²F      # m times do:
   D     # duplicate
    >    # increment
     }   # end loop
      )  # wrap in list
```

**Task 3**

```
v          # for each list in result of Task 2 do
 ¹L        # push range[1 ... n]
   N*      # multiply by index
     }     # end loop
      )    # wrap in list
       ¦   # discard first element
```

**Task 4**

```
˜          # flatten the result from Task 3
 {         # sort
```

Answer (score 3):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), <s>18</s> 17 bytes

#### Task 1

```
&:
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/matl#@69m9f@/CZclAA)

#### Task 2

```
&:O2G:h!+
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/matl#@69m5W/kbpWhqP3/vwmXJQA)

#### Task 3

```
&:O2G:h!+:7M!*
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/matl#@69m5W/kbpWhqG1l7quo9f@/CZclAA)

#### Task 4

```
&:O2G:h!+:7M!*1eS
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/matl#@69m5W/kbpWhqG1l7quoZZga/P@/CZclAA)

### Explanation

#### Task 1

```
&:    % Binary range [n n+1 ... m] from implicit inputs n, m
```

#### Task 2

```
      % ... Stack contains [n n+1 ... m]
O     % Push 0
2G    % Push second input, m
:     % Unary range: gives [1 2 ... m]
h     % Concatenate horizontally: gives [0 1 2 ... m]
!     % Transpose into a column vector
+     % Add with broadcast
```

#### Task 3

```
      % ... Stack contains matrix from task 2
:     % Unary range. For matrix input it uses its (1,1) entry. So this gives [1 2 ... n]
7M    % Push [1 2 ... m] again
!     % Transpose into a column vector
*     % Multiply with broadcast
```

#### Task 4

```
      % ... Stack contains matrix from task 3
1e    % Linearize into a row vector
S     % Sort
```

Answer (score 3):

### Mathematica, <strike>84</strike> 77 bytes

*Edit: Thanks to Martin Ender for saving 7 bytes.*

**Task 1:**

```
{n,m}n~Range~m
```

Pure `Function` with arguments `n` and `m` which outputs `n~Range~m`, the infix form of `Range[n,m]`.

**Task 2:**

```
{n,m}n~Range~m~Table~(m+1)//0~Range~m+#&
```

`n~Range~m~Table~(m+1)` creates a 2D array with `m+1` rows, where each row is the output of the previous task. Then `//0~Range~m+#&` is postfix application of the function `0~Range~m+#&` which effectively adds `0` to the first row, `1` to the second row, and so on up to `m` for the `m+1`-th row.

**Task 3:**

```
{n,m}n~Range~m~Table~(m+1)//0~Range~m+#&//1##&~Array~{n,m}&
```

This just applies the constant function `1##&~Array~{n,m}&` to the output of the previous task.

**Task 4:**

```
{n,m}n~Range~m~Table~(m+1)//0~Range~m+#&//1##&~Array~{n,m}&//Flatten//Sort
```

`Flatten`s and `Sort`s the multiplication table.

Answer (score 2):

## Python, 183 bytes

**Task 1, 29 bytes**

```python
r=range
a=lambda n,m:r(n,m+1)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/python2#@19kW5SYl57KlWibk5iblJKokKeTa1WkASS1DTX/FxRl5pUopGmkaJjoWGpq/gcA)

**Task 2, 84 bytes**

```python
r=range
a=lambda n,m:r(n,m+1)
s=lambda n,m:[[w+i for w in r(n,m)] for i in a(0,m+1)]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/python2#@19kW5SYl57KlWibk5iblJKokKeTa1WkASS1DTW5ipFFo6PLtTMV0vKLFMoVMvMUwIo0Y8ECmSCBRA0DsK7Y/wVFmXklCmkaKRomOpaamv8B)

**Task 3, 137 bytes**

```python
r=range
a=lambda n,m:r(n,m+1)
s=lambda n,m:[[w+i for w in r(n,m)] for i in a(0,m+1)]
d=lambda n,m:[[w*i for w in a(1,n)] for i in a(1,m)]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/python2#@19kW5SYl57KlWibk5iblJKokKeTa1WkASS1DTW5ipFFo6PLtTMV0vKLFMoVMvMUwIo0Y8ECmSCBRA0DsK5YrhQ0bVpI2hI1DHXyULUZgsz5X1CUmVeikKaRomGiY6mp@R8A)

**Task 4, <s>183</s>167 bytes**

```python
r=range
a=lambda n,m:r(n,m+1)
s=lambda n,m:[[w+i for w in r(n,m)] for i in a(0,m+1)]
d=lambda n,m:[[w*i for w in a(1,n)] for i in a(1,m)]
f=lambda(z):sorted(sum(z,[]))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/python2#Xcw7CsMwDIDh3afQKDUeaujSQE5iPKg4LobaKXJKIJfPw2RIugj0o0@LdML53SvuPpxeniHr1ApuszGkyrlaOzURwiAwQcxQj8jVEPfAeK/KKf/HbifGaHS@MrP/UeFAOFNbBhl7j@WXcNbWES1fiXmEgB4f@rntKw)

### Explanation:

**Task 1:**

Simple enough, it generates a `n` to `m` list using Python's built-in `range` function.

**Task 2:**

For every number `0` to `m+1`, it adds that number to each item of a list from `n` to `m`.

**Task 3:**

For each number from `1` to `m`, it multiplies that number by every number in a list from `1` to `n`.

**Task 4:**

This uses Python's built in `sorted` function which sorts a list from least to greatest. The list comprehension in the function is used to flatten the list. It creates a list of every item in every item of the list given to it by task 3.

- Saved very many bytes thanks to @math_junkie.
- Saved 16 bytes thanks to @ThisGuy

Saved very many bytes thanks to @math_junkie.

Comment: Can you not use anonymous functions or are lambdas not actually shorter? (by my count it seems they are)

Comment: Is this generally acceptable for Python asnwers? The code for task 2, for instance, isn't a full program with input and output, and it's also not a function or function definition.

Comment: @Cole I had to use non-anonymous functions so that I could use them in the later code.

Comment: @ngenisis I think it is okay, because the OP said the code for task 2 must start with the code for task 1, and the code for task 2, `def s(n,m):return [[w+i for w in r(n,m)] for i in a(0,m+1)]`, is a complete function when the code for task 1 defined.

Comment: You can do something like `a=lambda n,m:...` for each of your function definitions. Anonymous function are always shorter in python

Comment: It would save a few bytes (17) if you changed the list comprehension in 4 to `sum(w,[])`

Comment: Since `0<n<m` is a guarantee, the result from Task 1 is always truthy, meaning that Task 2 can attach itself using an `and`: `r=range;a=lambda n,m:r(n,m+1)and[[w+i for w in r(n,m)] for i in r(0,m+1)]` for -9 bytes. Taking it further, Task 3 tacks itself onto the end of *that* with `and[[w*i for w in r(1,n+1)] for i in r(1,m+1)]`! Task 4's addition stays about the same, although `lambda z:` is shorter than `lambda(z):`

Comment: @ValueInk Wow, I never would have thought of that. Ill make the changes when I get access to s computer.

Answer (score 2):

## PHP 7, 200 bytes

Uses the output buffer to clear previous output.

#### Task 1

```
[,$n,$m]=$argv;ob_start();eval($s='echo join(" ",$v?:range($n+$i,$m+$i)),"
";');
```

Saves the code in `$s` to reuse it later. The `$v` variable is for the last task.

#### Task 2

```
[,$n,$m]=$argv;ob_start();eval($s='echo join(" ",$v?:range($n+$i,$m+$i)),"
";');for(;++$i<=$m;)eval($s);
```

Prints the remaining lines.

#### Task 3

```
[,$n,$m]=$argv;ob_start();eval($s='echo join(" ",$v?:range($n+$i,$m+$i)),"
";');for(;++$i<=$m;)eval($s);for(($c=ob_clean)();++$j<=$m;print"
")for(;++$$j<=$n;sort($v))echo$v[]=$j*$$j,' ';
```

Clears the output buffer and prints the multiplication table, saving the numbers to `$v`.

#### Task 4

```
[,$n,$m]=$argv;ob_start();eval($s='echo join(" ",$v?:range($n+$i,$m+$i)),"
";');for(;++$i<=$m;)eval($s);for(($c=ob_clean)();++$j<=$m;print"
")for(;++$$j<=$n;sort($v))echo$v[]=$j*$$j,' ';$c();eval($s);
```

Clears the output buffer again and prints `$v`.

Answer (score 1):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), 126 bytes

#### Task 1

```powershell
param($n,$m)$n..$m
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/powershell#@1@QWJSYq6GSp6OSq6mSp6enkvv//3@T/5YA)

Uses the `..` built-in range operator. The default behavior for the implied `Write-Output` inserts a newline between elements, so that's why the output shows as newline separated.

---

#### Task 2

```powershell
param($n,$m)$n..$m>2;0..$m|%{$i=$_;($n..$m|%{$_+$i})-join','}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/powershell#@1@QWJSYq6GSp6OSq6mSp6enkmtnZG0AomtUq1UybVXirTUg4iB@vLZKZq2mblZ@Zp66jnrt////Tf5bAgA)

Dumps the first task to STDERR with `>2;`, then loops from `0` to `$m`, each iteration setting helper `$i` before looping again from `$n` to `$m` and incrementing each number by `$i`. Those are `-join`ed together with commas, else this would be an ambiguous gigantic long one-element-per-line output.

---

#### Task 3

```powershell
param($n,$m)$n..$m>2;0..$m|%{$i=$_;($n..$m|%{$_+$i})-join','}>2;(1..$m|%{$i=$_;(1..$n|%{$_*$i})-join' '})
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/powershell#@1@QWJSYq6GSp6OSq6mSp6enkmtnZG0AomtUq1UybVXirTUg4iB@vLZKZq2mblZ@Zp66jnotUKmGIapaEDcPrFQLoVRBvVbz////Jv8tAQ)

Same sort of thing `>2;` to dump the previous to STDERR. Then we simply double-loop from `1` to `$m` then `1` to `$n`, setting helper `$i` along the way, multiply the values, and `-join` with a space to make it tabular. Note the encapsulating parens -- they'll come into play on the next task -- but here they just ensure that the output is put onto the pipeline (which it already would be, so they're redundant).

---

#### Task 4

```powershell
param($n,$m)$n..$m>2;0..$m|%{$i=$_;($n..$m|%{$_+$i})-join','}>2;(1..$m|%{$i=$_;(1..$n|%{$_*$i})-join' '})-split' '|%{+$_}|sort
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/powershell#@1@QWJSYq6GSp6OSq6mSp6enkmtnZG0AomtUq1UybVXirTUg4iB@vLZKZq2mblZ@Zp66jnotUKmGIapaEDcPrFQLoVRBHcgqLsjJLAEygZLaKvG1NcX5RSX///83@W8JAA)

Aha! Finally some redundancy. Since the previous task has parens, we can tack on the `-split` on whitespace without worry, cast each one to an integer `|%{+$_}`, and then `|sort`. The output is again newline separated.

---

I *think* there are some ways to better leverage the redundancy between tasks -- still golfing it some.

Answer (score 1):

## ES2016-ish, <strike>401</strike> 384 chars

Here's a first try. I'm sure it could be condensed a bit, but it's pretty short. Arrow functions FTW! (Love those implicit return statements.) New and improved with template strings!

#### Task 1

```
var a=Array,l=console.log,f=(n,m)=>a.from(a(1+m-n),(w,i)=>n+i),z=(n,m)=>l(f(n,m).join`, `)
```

Call `z(n,m)` for the log output. (I'm aliasing console.log for later golfing.)

#### Task 2

Second verse... expands on the first.

```
var a=Array,l=console.log,f=(n,m)=>a.from(a(1+m-n),(w,i)=>n+i),z=(n,m)=>l(f(n,m).join`, `),p,o,g=(n,m)=>{p=n,o=m;return [...a(m+1).keys()].map((d)=>f(d+p,d+o))},y=(n,m)=>l(g(n,m).join`\n`
```

Now call `y(n,m)`. Pretty, no?

#### Task 3

Have to bypass most of the existing functionality `<sadface />`.

```
var a=Array,l=console.log,f=(n,m)=>a.from(a(1+m-n),(w,i)=>n+i),z=(n,m)=>l(f(n,m).join`, `),p,o,g=(n,m)=>{p=n,o=m;return [...a(m+1).keys()].map((d)=>f(d+p,d+o))},y=(n,m)=>l(g(n,m).join`\n`,h=(n,m)=>[...a(m).keys()].map((d)=>(d+1)*n).join`\t`,i=(n,m)=>[...a(n).keys()].map((d)=>h((d+1),m)),v=(n,m)=>i(n,m).join`\n`
```

Now the method name is `v`. Call it the same way.

#### Task 4

And now we can reuse again.

```
var a=Array,l=console.log,f=(n,m)=>a.from(a(1+m-n),(w,i)=>n+i),z=(n,m)=>l(f(n,m).join`, `),p,o,g=(n,m)=>{p=n,o=m;return [...a(m+1).keys()].map((d)=>f(d+p,d+o))},y=(n,m)=>l(g(n,m).join`\n`,h=(n,m)=>[...a(m).keys()].map((d)=>(d+1)*n).join`\t`,i=(n,m)=>[...a(n).keys()].map((d)=>h((d+1),m)),v=(n,m)=>i(n,m).join`\n`,t=(n,m)=>l(v(n,m).match(/\d+/g).sort((a,b)=>+a>+b||+(a===b)*2-1).join(`, `)
```

Had to skip `u` for my method, so it's `t`. Bummed that I had to put in that sort function, because the `String.match` returns values as... strings.

Answer (score 0):

## Ruby, <s>121</s> 103 bytes

Everything in Ruby is truthy except for `nil` and `false`, which means that the tasks can be set up to ignore previous input with naught but a well-placed `and`/`&&`.

**Task 1**

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/ruby#@5@nk2uroqWXm1igoGZVkh@fyVWgEK2Vp6eXG/v//3/j/@YA)

```ruby
n,m=$*.map &:to_i
p [*n..m]
```

**Task 2**

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/ruby#@5@nk2uroqWXm1igoGZVkh@fyVWgEK2Vp6eXG6umpmEApDVBktU1mTVAYe1MoIB2Zmzt////jf@bAwA)

```ruby
n,m=$*.map &:to_i
p [*n..m]&&(0..m).map{|i|[*n+i..m+i]}
```

**Task 3**

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/ruby#@5@nk2uroqWXm1igoGZVkh@fyVWgEK2Vp6eXG6umpmEApDVBktU1mTVAYe1MoIB2ZmwtUM4QWQ7Ey4PysmoytbJqa////2/83xwA)

```ruby
n,m=$*.map &:to_i
p [*n..m]&&(0..m).map{|i|[*n+i..m+i]}&&(1..m).map{|i|(1..n).map{|j|i*j}}
```

**Task 4**

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/ruby#@5@nk2uroqWXm1igoGZVkh@fyVWgEK2Vp6eXG6umpmEApDVBktU1mTVAYe1MoIB2ZmwtUM4QWQ7Ey4PysmoytbJqa/XSchJLSlLz9Irzi0r@//9v/N8cAA)

```ruby
n,m=$*.map &:to_i
p [*n..m]&&(0..m).map{|i|[*n+i..m+i]}&&(1..m).map{|i|(1..n).map{|j|i*j}}.flatten.sort
```